# Live stream thumbnails from API v2 not valid half the time

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, youtube-api, live

**Overall:** I cannot get valid thumbnails for youtube live streams (about 40% to 50% of streams ' thumbnails I get back are invalid/404 - gray "no screenshot" image) when pulling from the API v2.

**Details:** Here is what I am using to grab the streams:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/live/events/live_now?v=2&alt=json&inline=true&max-results=20&start-index=1&fields=entry(published,updated,title,author(name),content(entry(media:group)))
```

Within "media$thumbnail" I am getting data (6 thumbnail items), and on half the entries it gives me the gray "no screenshot" icon for all 6 screenshots. The other half usually gives me back half valid thumbnails and half invalid. So I may get back the default images (high def and regulars), and it won't give me the numbered images (0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.).

I have tried using the only two variations of url that I know of:

```
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/[VID-ID]/default.jpg

http://img.youtube.com/vi/[VID-ID]/0.jpg
```

From the live stream site, there are no invalid thumbnails which to me would suggest that all live streams have a valid thumbnail, or does that mean that youtube does not show streams that do not have valid thumbnails? I also noticed that they switch quite a bit between using 1.jpg and default.jpg, is there a way though the api to tell which image is preferred?

Thanks for any help on this subject!

Jake

Comment: I certainly do see live videos that don't have thumbnails associated with them, and I'm assuming it's because the creator didn't associate a placeholder thumbnail when creating the event. If you could provide a video id corresponding to something that _does_ have a thumbnail when viewed on YouTube.com but not via the API, I can follow up.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for your response! Here are some examples below:

Comment: There seems to be a thumbnail on youtube yet no valid thumbnails returned in API ===

dTBPycjJjjQ: 2012-10-18 МММ-История: Александр Мелихов,
iATCxiLhfkI: Dart for Web Apps,
1KGHr-rwLs4: A State of Trance 600 LIVE broadcast Oct 18th, 8pm CET =====

These examples are on the main page in the "live now" section (at least at time of writing)

I am using the following query string =====

    https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/live/events/live_now?v=2&alt=json&inline=true&max-results=20&start-index=1&fields=entry(published,updated,title,author(name),content(entry(media:group))) =====

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you're seeing this with video ids that correspond to "Hangouts on Air", which are Google+ Hangouts that are broadcast live via YouTube. They use a different setup than normal scheduled YouTube Live events, and you can't, for instance, create a thumbnail in advance of the broadcast (since the live event is created on the fly).

Comment: Thanks Jeff for looking into this, I really just wanted to make sure. We shouldn't have a problem once we get our application up and running. I believe we will be a partner using a developer tag, so I should be able to pull just our feeds, and all of those will likely have legitimate thumbnails.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that is having this problem with getting correct thumbnails for YouTube live streams. By calling the json API, I was able to get the actual thumbnails returned for my live stream. These are the same thumbnails used on YouTube's site. Apparently they use a different URI pattern for live streams:

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{YOUTUBE_ID}}/default_live.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{YOUTUBE_ID}}/mqdefault_live.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{YOUTUBE_ID}}/hqdefault_live.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{YOUTUBE_ID}}/sddefault_live.jpg
```